# FindBugs can't locate org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException

Tags: java, linux, ant, fedora, findbugs

I installed the Fedora 20 findbugs RPMs, and set up my Ant `build.xml` file thusly:

```
<property name="findbugs.home" location="/usr/share/findbugs"/>

<target name="findbugs" description="static bytecode analysis">
    <taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask">
    </taskdef>

    <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}" output="xml" outputFile="bcel-fb.xml">
        <sourcePath path="${src.dir}"/>
        <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
        </fileset>
    </findbugs>
</target>
```

This gives me the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find findbugs.jar in /usr/share/findbugs/lib

So I make `/usr/share/findbugs/lib` a symbolic link to `/usr/share/java`, where `findbugs.jar` lives.  That gets me a bit further, but now it spits out:

```
findbugs:
 [findbugs] Executing findbugs from ant task
 [findbugs] Running FindBugs...
 [findbugs] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassFormatException
```

`strace` shows that it found and opened `/usr/share/java/findbugs-bcel.jar`, so I have no idea why it can't load the class.  Explicitly adding `/usr/share/java/findbugs-bcel.jar` to the taskdef's classpath doesn't change anything.

**NOTE**: I'm not trying to run FindBugs on BCEL.  BCEL is used by FindBugs to do its analysis, and my own code doesn't use BCEL at all.

Comment: Findbugs uses it's own privately modified version of BCEL. make sure your classpath is using the one from Findbugs.

Answer (score 5):

You need an `<Auxclasspath/>` subentity pointing to the classpath you used when you compiled. Findbugs uses the built `*.class` files, and needs the source to pinpoint in the source code where an error is, the classes you're analyzing, and the classpath to all of your third party jars to be able to understand the code:

```
 <findbugs
     home="${findbugs.home}" 
     output="xml" 
     outputFile="bcel-fb.xml">
     <auxClasspath refid="main.classpath"/>  <!-- Third party jars classpath   -->
     <class location="${main.destdir}"/>     <!-- Class files you're analyzing -->
     <sourcePath path="${main.srcdir}"/>     <!-- Source directory             -->
 </findbugs>
```

By the way, you should put the findbugs jar inside your project (My preference would be under `${basedir}/antlib/findbugs`) and use that in your `<taskdef/>`:

```
<taskdef name="findbugs" 
    classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask">
    <classpath>
       <fileset dir="${basedir}/antlib/findbugs"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

This way, Findbugs is part of your project. Anyone who checks out your project will automatically have the findbugs jar and will be able to run your findbugs task without having to download the jar and installing it in `$ANT_HOME/lib`.

I do this with any optional Ant task jars like PMD, Checkstyle, and Ant-Contrib. It makes it much easier for others to be able to run my builds, and I spend less time trying to explain to people where they can get that jar, and how to install it. Plus, if you use a Continuous Build system like Jenkins, you don't have to futz with the server anytime you add in a new optional jar.

Comment: 1) I tried adding the `<auxClasspath>` element, and it didn't help; same error as before.  2) The manual says that that element is "An optional nested element which specifies a classpath ... containing classes used by the analyzed library or application, but which you don't want to analyze".  I'm not using the BCEL library in my app, so I don't see why it would help FindBugs load one of the libraries *it's* using to *do* the analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this,

**Adding task definition**

```
<taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"/>
```

**Defining target**

```
<property name="findbugs.home" value="/export/home/daveho/work/findbugs" />

  <target name="findbugs" depends="jar">
    <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}"
              output="xml"
              outputFile="bcel-fb.xml" >
      <auxClasspath path="${basedir}/lib/Regex.jar" />
      <sourcePath path="${basedir}/src/java" />
      <class location="${basedir}/bin/bcel.jar" />
    </findbugs>
  </target>
```

This target will execute FindBugs on bcel.jar, which is the Jar file produced by BCEL's build script. (By making it depend on the "jar" target, we ensure that the library is fully compiled before running FindBugs on it.) The output of FindBugs will be saved in XML format to a file called bcel-fb.xml. An auxiliary Jar file, Regex.jar, is added to the aux classpath, because it is referenced by the main BCEL library. A source path is specified so that the saved bug data will have accurate references to the BCEL source code.

For more [info](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html).

Comment: @Matthew Cline Did you tried it with above solution> Are you still facing issues?

Comment: I'm not trying to run FindBugs *on* BCEL, rather FindBugs uses BCEL to do the analysis of my own code.

Comment: It could be beacuse you are  using the same version of Findbugs and the jar file is named bcel.jar not bcel-1.0.jar. You are also running Findbugs from an Ant script. Try to download the Findbugs once again, unpack it in the place of your current one and run your script once again.

Comment: Try to download findbugs once again and also update your bcel.jar according to the version that findbugs requires.

Comment: I also get that you are not running findbugs on bcel, but the code was just a demonstration for findbugs and setting the dependant jars.

Comment: I installed findbugs as RPMs from the standard Fedora 20 repository.  Should I remove that and install directly from the FindBugs site?

Answer (score 1):

If findbugs is not located at:
`<property name="findbugs.home" location="/usr/share/findbugs"/>`

I would change your Ant Findbugs config to the location of the Findbug library files:

`<property name="findbugs.home" location="/usr/share/java"/>`
Or even,
`<property name="findbugs.home" location="/usr/share/java/findbugs"/>` is this is the directory.

It does look like a classpath issue.

Comment: I tried changing the findbugs home as suggested, but it didn't help.  Also, `/usr/share/findbugs/etc/script.properties` contains `findbugs_home=/usr/share/findbugs`, so I'm pretty sure that `/usr/share/findbugs` is the proper home.

Answer (score 1):

According to Richard Fearn [1] Fedora repackages findbugs jars and modifies the way the FB library classes are loaded, so by using findbugs from fedora one must use workaround described below. See also [2] for the original bug request at findbugs.

Quote from [1]:

> As a workaround it's possible to do this:
>
> ```
> <findbugs classpath="/usr/share/java/findbugs.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-findbugs.jar:/usr/share/java/apache-commons-lang.jar:/usr/share/java/dom4j.jar:/usr/share/java/findbugs-bcel.jar:/usr/share/java/jaxen.jar:/usr/share/java/jcip-annotations.jar:/usr/share/java/jFormatString.jar:/usr/share/java/jsr-305.jar:/usr/share/java/junit.jar:/usr/share/java/objectweb-asm/asm.jar:/usr/share/java/objectweb-asm/asm-commons.jar:/usr/share/java/objectweb-asm/asm-tree.jar">
> ```
>
> where that classpath is the output from:
>
> $ build-classpath `cat /etc/ant.d/findbugs`

[1] https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1080682#c4

[2] https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1255/

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not exactly matching the Fedora package case in the question, I hit this same issue trying to fetch FindBugs (3.0.1) using Ivy rather than install it from the .zip distribution.  There seem to be a number of mis-matches between what gets fetched and what findbugs expects.

In the end I used this dependency in my ivy.xml:

```
<dependency org="com.google.code.findbugs" name="findbugs" rev="3.0.1" conf="findbugs->default" />
```

with the following in my ant build.xml (within a 'bootstrap' task which sets up all the tools):

```
<property name="findbugs.home" value="${basedir}/tools/findbugs" />
<property name="findbugs.lib" value="${findbugs.home}/lib" />
<ivy:resolve file="${basedir}/tools/ivy.xml" conf="findbugs" trransitive="true"/>
<ivy:retrieve conf="findbugs" transitive="true" pattern="${findbugs.lib}/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
```

This gives a tree like:

```
AppleJavaExtensions-1.4.jar
asm-5.0.2.jar
asm-commons-5.0.2.jar
asm-debug-all-5.0.2.jar
asm-tree-5.0.2.jar
bcel-findbugs-6.0.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
findbugs-3.0.1.jar
jaxen-1.1.6.jar
jcip-annotations-1.0.jar
jFormatString-2.0.1.jar
jsr305-2.0.1.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

The key to solving the problem is that `findbugs-3.0.1.jar` wants to use the classpath specified in its own `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Class-Path: bcel-6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar dom4j-1.6.1.jar jaxen-1.1.6.jar asm-debug-all-5.0.2.jar jsr305.jar jFormatString.jar commons-lang-2.6.jar
```

Also it wants to be named `findbugs.jar` otherwise a different error occurs.
Therefore after the Ivy step, rename the .jars using Ant:

```
    <move file="${findbugs.lib}/findbugs-3.0.1.jar" tofile="${findbugs.lib}/findbugs.jar"/>
    <move file="${findbugs.lib}/jFormatString-2.0.1.jar" tofile="${findbugs.lib}/jFormatString.jar"/>
    <move file="${findbugs.lib}/jsr305-2.0.1.jar" tofile="${findbugs.lib}/jsr305.jar"/>
    <move file="${findbugs.lib}/bcel-findbugs-6.0.jar" tofile="${findbugs.lib}/bcel-6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
```

Finally define the Ant taskdef:

```
    <taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${findbugs.lib}" includes="*.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
```

Answer (score 0):

Findbugs uses it's own privately modified version of BCEL. make sure your classpath is using the one from Findbugs

Comment: `strace` shows that it's successfully opening it's own BCEL jar file, so that's not the problem.